# Unable to connect MySQL to registration page using a functions file

Tags: php, mysql, function

//I keep getting an error message when trying to link my functions.inc file to my php registration page, I think it has something to do with my directory.

//This is the php code linking to my functions.inc file:

```
<?php require_once("functions.inc"); ?>
```

//This is my functions.inc code:

```
<?php
           //generic file for generic functions and other includes
           session_start();
           require_once("../dbstuff.inc");
           require_once("validation.inc");
?>
```

//This is my dbstuff.inc code:

```
<?php
          define("DBHOST", "localhost");
          define("DBUSER", "cs12jkk_cs12jkk");
          define("DBPASS", "******");
          define("DB","cs12jkk_customer");
?>
```

//This is the error message I receive in my browser:

```
Warning: require_once(â€œdbstuffincâ€): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/Application/functions.inc on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'â€œdbstuffincâ€' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cs12jkk/public_html/Application/functions.inc on line 4
```

//I have uploaded my files to my server in public_html>application>RegistrationPage.php,dbstuff.inc,functions.inc

Comment: Are you sure, that dbstuff.inc file is in parent directory?

Comment: sorry to be a pain, I'm trying to make a website with a log in system for my university course! How do I check if it is in the parent directory?

Comment: the index of my site can be seen cs12jkk.icsnewmedia.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message your getting is telling you that the file you need is missing.

Using ".../" is a risky, as it the command is saying *go up one level in directories and look for the file there*. This works well, as long as your only ever one directory in

Try changing the requires to look at the full file path (Assuming file path, you will need to put the actual paths in)

i.e.

`require_once("/var/www/html/dbstuff.inc");
require_once("/var/www/html/validation.inc");`

See if that works, if it does, its because of your use of the "../" call and where you are loading your main webpage for.

I've also noticed that your validation.inc page is not called using a directory change, if they are both in the same place, you could remove the "../" and try again.

**EDIT** :- As all your pages are in the same directory, you do not need to call any directory changes. From the page you have linked, you can see all 4 files your using. As such, by using ../ you are asking it to look in the directory above, /home/cs12jkk/, instead of /home/cs12jkk/public_html/ where the file is actually stored

**EDIT 2** :- My code:

Registration Page:

```
<?php require_once("functions.inc");
echo "We are loaded";
?>
```

Functions Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbstuff.inc");
require_once("validation.inc"); 
?>
```

dbstuff.inc:

```
<?php
define("DBHOST", "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "cs12jkk_cs12jkk");
define("DBPASS", "******");
define("DB","cs12jkk_customer");
?>
```

and finally, validation.inc

```
<?php
?>
```

From this, I get a page that says "We are loaded" with no errors.

Comment: Having just looked at your webpage its because of your use of ../ when you require your dbstuff.inc file. Remove the ../ and you should see your problems go away.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message, thanks for all your help though! I don't know what i'm doing wrong i've removed the ../

Comment: I have just created the same pages, copying your code and I get the error `Warning: require_once(../dbstuff.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/newtoolset/tools/Testing/functions.inc on line 4`

As its specifying the file, and reason, its possible that your file has some hidden characters. Delete and recreate your dbstuff.inc file.

Once I removed the "../" the pages worked and loaded without any issues for me

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, i've got it working! You have saved my bacon haha

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you mentioned, it is crashing on line 4. So it seems that you have not placed validation.inc up there on your server...Kindly confirm that you have that file there? So Either comment out the line 4 and check if it still gives the error or not...Or Secondly place the validation file up there...

Comment: my validation file is on the server; they're all viewable at cs12jkk.icsnewmedia.net I'm so confused at what I am doing wrong

Comment: what it seems to me is that inc extension is playing something...can you use php extensions or are they not allowed?

Comment: also try  require_once("../dbstuff.inc"); without ../ coz it seems that both the files are in same directory...so replace  require_once("../dbstuff.inc"); with  require_once("dbstuff.inc");

Comment: i've changed it to that and still getting the same error message, thanks for your help though!

Comment: ok change the linking line to this

<?php require_once("functions.php"); ?> 

and rewrite the function.php again with the following code

<?php
           //generic file for generic functions and other includes
           session_start();
           require_once("dbstuff.inc");
           require_once("validation.inc");
?>

and run and see if it works